# Mosaic Template attachments

Tags: mailing, mosaico, attachments

I am trying to create a member enquiry template for mailing to members who enquire through our website.  We use Mosaico for our mailings.  Is there any way to create a mosaico template with static attachments included?

Comment: Could you just include a download link to the attachment?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's one option - thank you.